# fastlane action and plugin difference

Tags: fastlane

I have a use case where I have to generate release versions for testing builds that follow a well documented pipeline playbook set by our testers. I already have a function that runs the logic in ruby, but I am considering creating fastlane action or fastlane plugin. Under my use case, is action sufficient or I should consider a plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fastlane **plugins** are similar to cocoapods pods:

- you specify plugin name, version, dependencies and other info in a **gemspec** file (podspec alike)
- you can have nested dependencies between plugins (Fastfile <- plugin1 <-plugin2 <- .. )
- you save them in a proper repo
- plugin is made of a set of actions or plugins
- you add a plugin dependency via command:

`fastlane add_plugin [plugin_name]`

So, it's better to use plugins if you need its actions in many different places and/or you need to build up a composite plugin hierarchy structure.

---

Otherwise, fastlane **actions** are simple ruby files directly invoked from Fastfile, that can take input parameters, nonetheless see environment variables and can have a return parameter.

In order to 'clean' your code,  fastlane actions could suffice.